# How does one get a tree view in HTML to have hover effect on its nodes that span the full width of the tree?

Tags: html, css

I have a tree view like below.  When I create a hover css effect, it applies only as far as the child node width.
See  https://jsfiddle.net/maxm007/Le3cj4s0/ to see what I mean.

How can I get it to apply to the full width of the tree?

```
<div class="tree-item">
   <div class="tree-item-content">
      Parent
   </div>
   <div class="tree-item-children">
    <div class="tree-item">

       <div class="tree-item-content">
          Child 1
       </div>
       <div class="tree-item-children">
          <div class="tree-item">
           <div class="tree-item-content">
             Grandchild
           </div>
           <div class="tree-item-children">
           </div>
      </div>   
       </div>
    </div>      
    <div class="tree-item">
       <div class="tree-item-content">
          Child 2
       </div>
       <div class="tree-item-children">
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you looking for a CSS only solution? Because you could apply classes with javascript to the parents and get the outcome you want

Comment: Yes it has to be css because I’m in VueJs  and direct manipulation of dom isn’t an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution could be using a pseudo element and work, for example, on its property `transform:translateX(-100%)`;

```css
.tree-item-children {
  padding-left:25px
}

.tree-item-content{
  position:relative;
}

.tree-item-content::after{
  height:100%;
  content:"";
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;right:0;
  transform:translateX(-100%);
  width:100%;
}

.tree-item-content:hover,
.tree-item-content:hover::after{
  background:yellow
}
```

```html
<div class="tree-item">
   <div class="tree-item-content">
      Parent
   </div>
   <div class="tree-item-children">
    <div class="tree-item">
       <div class="tree-item-content">
          Child 1
       </div>
       <div class="tree-item-children">
          <div class="tree-item">
           <div class="tree-item-content">
             Grandchild
           </div>
           <div class="tree-item-children">
           </div>
      </div>   
       </div>
    </div>      
    <div class="tree-item">
       <div class="tree-item-content">
          Child 2
       </div>
       <div class="tree-item-children">
       </div>
    </div>      
   
      
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, that worked and I have absolutely no idea how these pseudo elements work.  Thanks.

Comment: Makes more sense, now I read this. https://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-roundup/

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, it seems a good link. There are a lot of useful guides on the web about pseudo element. I'm glad I helped you. :-)